# How to increase picture using html code with yii2 syntax?

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

Hy guys, following code will increase picture by clicking on it:

```
      <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-1.jpg"><img  src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-1.jpg" alt="image-1" /></a>
```

)

In my yii2 application, I have following  valid picture-url in anonymous function:

```
 $url = '@web/img/' . $bild->dateiname;
```

How to tranform upper code in yii2 syntax. I try like this, but it's not working:

```html
return  Html::a(
        Html::img($url, ['alt' => 'PicNotFound', 'class' => 'img-circle', 'style' => 'width:225px;height:225px']
                  ), [Html::img($url, ['alt' => 'PicNotFound']
                                )], ['title' => 'Immobiliendaten abrufen', 'data' => ['pjax' => '0'], 'class' => 'example-image-link']
);
```

Firedebug will show following html-code. url in link is wrong!

```
a class="example-image-link" href="/yii2_ErkanImmo/frontend/web/index.php/" title="Immobiliendaten abrufen"><img class="img-circle" src="/yii2_ErkanImmo/frontend/web/img/villa1.jpg" alt="PicNotFound" style="width:125px;height:125px;">event
<img class="img-circle" src="/yii2_ErkanImmo/frontend/web/img/villa1.jpg" alt="PicNotFound" style="width:125px;height:125px;">
</a>
```

**Rephrasing question**

I will get output as shown up at my attachement after having clicked on picture using code like this:

```
    return Html::a(Html::img($url, ['alt' => 'image-1']), $url, ['class' => 'example-image-link']);[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Here is complete code of view file(for GRU)

```html
 [
                'attribute' => $dummy,
                'label' => Yii::t('app', ''),
                'format' => 'html', // sorgt dafür,dass das HTML im return gerendert wird
                'vAlign' => 'middle',
                'value' => function($model) {
                    $bmp = '/bmp/';
                    $tif = '/tif/';
                    $png = '/png/';
                    $psd = '/psd/';
                    $pcx = '/pcx/';
                    $gif = '/gif/';
                    $jpeg = '/jpeg/';
                    $jpg = '/jpg/';
                    $ico = '/ico/';
                    try {
                        $bilder = \frontend\models\Dateianhang::GetBild($model);
                        foreach ($bilder as $bild) {
                            if (preg_match($bmp, $bild->dateiname) || preg_match($tif, $bild->dateiname) || preg_match($png, $bild->dateiname) || preg_match($psd, $bild->dateiname) || preg_match($pcx, $bild->dateiname) || preg_match($gif, $bild->dateiname) || preg_match($jpeg, $bild->dateiname) || preg_match($jpg, $bild->dateiname) || preg_match($ico, $bild->dateiname)) {
                                $url = '@web/img/' . $bild->dateiname;
                            }
                        }
return Html::a(Html::img($url, ['alt' => 'image-1', 'class' => 'img-circle', 'style' => 'width:225px;height:225px']), $url, ['class' => 'example-image-link', 'title' => 'Touch picture to increase', 'target' => '_blank']);
                        //return Html::img($url, ['alt' => 'Bewerberbild nicht vorhanden', 'class' => 'img-circle', 'style' => 'width:225px;height:225px']);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
 ],
```

Neither picture will be increased, nor target=>_blank is doing its job :=(

Answer (score 0):

Try following code -

```
<?php
$url = 'http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-1.jpg';
//in your case
//$url = '@web/img/'.$bild->dateiname;
echo Html::a(
  Html::img($url, ['alt'=>'image-1']),
$url, ['class'=>'example-image-link']);
?>
```

If you want to redirect to some action in controller, replace `$url` in last line with `['/controller/action']`

Comment: html code being created is correct. But picture won't be shown(see rephrasing question above)

Comment: @tklustig i would like to see your view file, to see understand whats wrong happened.

Comment: Okay. Here, it is(see second picture)

Comment: No second picture. I prospect U to see code, don't U? Complete code of GridColumn just has been inserted.

Comment: P.S.: I use pjax. Maybe this is reason for applications' behaviour?

Comment: @tklustig is your image good..? are u saving it with proper extention..?